# boost::ptr_vector member function list

Tags: c++, boost, ptr-vector

i am having trouble finding what member functions boost::ptr_vector has..

all i can find is http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html, but that doesnt list push_back() which i know is definitely a function..

is there a resource anywhere that i am able to find which functions can be used with boost::ptr_vector and their prototypes?

specifically i am interested if there is an "insert" type function, similar to the STL vector.insert()

any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at it's superclass:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_sequence_adapter.html

That's where `push_back` is defined. It's using an `std::vector` underneath :)